# How to use oracle to orchard 1.10?

Tags: oracle, orchardcms

I want use oracle 11g to orchard 1.10, how can i do?
I find a doc ,tell me how to do,but tha't doc is too old for orchard 1.10?
doc url:
http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/401440

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that discussion is way to old for orchard 1.10.
The database has significantly changed since then.